# Can't register ecs task with docker hub private repository image

Tags: amazon-ecs

I want to run an ECS task with a docker image from private docker hub repository.

I followed all instructions in this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html .

Then I created a task definition json:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "signage-next-graphql",
      "image": "docker.io/private/next-graphql:latest",
      "repositoryCredentials": {
        "credentialsParameter": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2: 385945872227:secret:dockerhub-personal-pTsU9e"
      },
      "memory": 500,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5000,
          "containerPort": 5000
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [],
  "memory": "900",
  "cpu": "128",
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "family": "next-graphql",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::385945872227:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "taskRoleArn": ""
}
```

when I run `aws ecs register-task-definition --family "${ECS_TASK_FAMILY}" --cli-input-json "file://./ecsTaskDefinition.json" --region "${AWS_TARGET_REGION}"` , i'm getting the error;

> Unknown parameter in containerDefinitions[0]: "repositoryCredentials",
>   must be one of: name, image, cpu, memory, memoryReservation, links,
>   portMappings, essential, entryPoint, command, environment,
>   mountPoints, volumesFrom, linuxParameters, hostname, user,
>   workingDirectory, disableNetworking, privileged,
>   readonlyRootFilesystem, dnsServers, dnsSearchDomains, extraHosts,
>   dockerSecurityOptions, dockerLabels, ulimits, logConfiguration,
>   healthCheck

Is aws documentation not updated? I'd expect it to be up to date.

Comment: Is your CLI up-to date?. Can you please provide the CLI version and ECS Agent or Fargate versions as well?.

Comment: pip shows my awscli version is  1.15.22.  ECS agent version is 1.17.2

Comment: gosh, it was cli version, thank you @Imran!